# Переход на другой экран из viewDidLoad (Whose view is not in the window hierarchy!)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Осуществляю переход, если не удалось загрузить данные, попадаю внутрь цикла и выдает предупреждение: Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
При этом переход не срабатывает.

P.S. Тот же переход работает при нажатии на кнопку.

```
@implementation ViewControllerTable

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

// Загрузка
_lineNameProfile = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"lineNameProfile"];
_linePassword = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"linePassword"];
if(_lineNameProfile.length == 0){
    ViewController *viewControllerConnect = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerConnect"];
    [self presentViewController:viewControllerConnect animated:YES completion:nil];
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

viewDidLoad вызывается когда vc.view только только создалась. Она может быть еще не добавлена на экран. Замени этот метод на viewWillAppear (вызывается перед началом отображения текущего контроллера). Или на viewDidAppear, так может быть красивей анимация.

PS: когда ты нажимаешь на кнопку, то контроллер уже создан, загружен и добавлен на экран. В этом случае уже можно полноценно работать с дочерними контроллерами.